# How to build the system for automatic site creation

Tags: php, linux, joomla

i have the following task and i don't know how to proceed. My copnay has many html templates for websites . we have our own Linux server for web hosting .
we mainly use php and or joomla for websites.

Now my company wants to build a master system or web interface (if safe)

where on first screen i have various templates to choose then next page i have screen to enter the site names dbname etc and site gets automatically generated with sample data and then my manager can chnage with actual data.

There may be few more things but if anyone can guide me how to achieve this

thanks

Comment: Install a CMS that lets you do this.

Comment: any example for cms like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a so called autoinstaller. There are ready made solutions for this kind of scenario around : Softaculous, Fantastico, Installatron, cPanel and so on.
Two are explicitly mentioned on the Joomla Documentation :

http://docs.joomla.org/Installing_Joomla_using_an_AutoInstaller

Fantastico  https://netenberg.com/#fantastico.html (90$)
Softaculous http://www.softaculous.com/ (24$ / Free)

As for the templates you can put them into the installed package and choose later on or create different Packages, or use a fronted template chooser extension for Joomla.

Comment: thanks buddy you saved my life . i could not understood frontend chooser extension , what is that

Comment: Most people don't get how to change the template in the backend - so i install an article in the front explaining how to do that and an extension like this http://www.ultijoomla.com/downloads?func=fileinfo&id=5 or similar one for wordpress etc. so the user can get a look and feel of the different installed templates directly from the first (front)page. Like here : http://www.pixelsparadise.com/showcase/

Answer (score 0):

That's not really difficult. Just upload your default files:

```
foreach (glob("src/$template/*") as $fn) {
    copy($fn, "ftp://user:name@ftp.hoster.com/htdocs/".basename($fn));
}
// Well, not quite. But something like that.
```

And for the second screen, provide a form, save that as config file (ini-style or var_export() for a config.php script), and upload that as well.

The rest of your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholders in a text file (template.txt) and then replace them with the inputted data, previously stored in the database. Remember to leave the placeholders as comment, so that the page can be edited later, storing the data in the database. Or just deleting the data from the database and editing the text inside the placeholders.
example:

```
<--! placeholder1start --><b>INPUTTED TEXT</b> <--!placeholder1end-->
```

Hope that helps.